# matrix multiplication resulting in values greater than 255

Tags: c++, opencv

If I am performing matrix multiplication on two 8UC1 images, or per element multiplication, what happens if one of the resulting pixel values is greater than 255? For example, if in image A a certain pixel has value 100, and in image B that same pixel has value 150 (for the per element multiplication case), then clearly 100*150 > 255 - so does that pixel simply get truncated to 255 value? And if so is there some transformation I can make to preserve that information without having it truncated?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: How would that help anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

opencv will saturate the result for a uchar img.

to avoid that, use e.g. the dtype flag in [multiply](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multiply) and specify a type larger than your input

```
Mat a, b; //input, CV_8U
Mat c;    // output, yet unspecified

multiply( a,b, c, 1, CV_32S ); // c will be of int type, untruncated results
```